# std::getline stuck on end of piped input

Tags: c++, stdio

I am failing to parse this file:

```
1

3
John Doe
Jane Smith
Jane Austen
1 2 3
2 1 3
2 3 1
1 2 3
3 1 2
```

With the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{

    int cases, candidates_number;
    char candidates[20][80];
    int votes[20][1000];
    int votes_count[20];

    std::string line;

    std::cin >> cases;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

    for (int i=0; i<cases; i++) {

        std::cin >> candidates_number;
        std::cin.get();

        for (int j=0; j<candidates_number; j++) {
            std::cin.getline(candidates[j], sizeof(candidates[j]), '\n');
        }

        int votes_number = 0;

        while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            if (line.empty()) {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << line;
            votes_number++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In particular, the process gets stuck in the while loop after reading the last line of the file. I am invoking my program through the "Standard input" feature in Eclipse.

Why isn't `std::getline` failing and causing the program to finish?

---

Problem requirements:

> Australian ballots require that voters rank all the candidates in
>   order of choice. Initially only the first choices are counted, and if
>   one candidate receives more than 50% of the vote then that candidate
>   is elected. However, if no candidate receives more than 50%, all
>   candidates tied for the lowest number of votes are eliminated. Ballots
>   ranking these candidates first are recounted in favor of their
>   highest-ranked non-eliminated candidate. This process of eliminating
>   the weakest candidates and counting their ballots in favor of the
>   preferred non-eliminated candidate continues until one candidate
>   receives more than 50% of the vote, or until all remaining candidates
>   are tied.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input begins with a single positive integer on a line by itself
>   indicating the number of cases following, each as described below.
>   This line is followed by a blank line. There is also a blank line
>   between two consecutive inputs.
>
> The first line of each case is an integer n$ \le$20 indicating the
>   number of candidates. The next n lines consist of the names of the
>   candidates in order, each up to 80 characters in length and containing
>   any printable characters. Up to 1,000 lines follow, each containing
>   the contents of a ballot. Each ballot contains the numbers from 1 to n
>   in some order. The first number indicates the candidate of first
>   choice; the second number indicates candidate of second choice, and so
>   on.
>
> **Output**
>
> The output of each test case consists of either a single line
>   containing the name of the winner or several lines containing the
>   names of all candidates who are tied. The output of each two
>   consecutive cases are separated by a blank line.

Comment: using `getline` with `cin` will just wait forever for more input from stdin no matter how much input you've already given it, it will wait for more.

Comment: The code terminates as expected for me.

Comment: Please don't mix `std::cin` and `std::getline` - it's a mess.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, how would you do it? The number of lines following the names is not known and I need to detect a possible empty line, that is why I'm using `std::getline`

Comment: Do you need them to be `char*` or can they be `std::string`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl any idea of what could be the difference between my environment and yours? Are there any requirements for a "valid" input file? Blank line at the end or something?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: if the file is invalid, the loops terminate. The most likely difference is that you somehow arranged for you `cat` to not terminate, e.g. using `cat input - | program`. Try `program < input` instead...

Comment: Thanks @DietmarKühl, my bad, I was actually running the program through Eclipse, thinking it was the same as doing it from the console, but my input was treated as interactive input instead and didn't terminate.

Comment: To be clear, there's nothing wrong with calling `std::getline()` or `istream::getline()`.against `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program was actually correct, but I was feeding the input file through Eclipse in the wrong way (it was treated as interactive input):

[image]

Using a program argument `< input` instead works as expected:

[image]